# Show and Hide a DIV based on a variable PHP jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to Hide/Show a `DIV` based upon a Variable. This is what I have so far.

I `POST` the variable into an `INPUT`

```
<input type="text" id="showhidediv" name="showhidediv" value="<?php echo $ta; ?>">
```

This is my jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var show=('#showhidediv');
    if(show == 2) {
        $('#landlord').show();
    }
    else if(show == 1)
    {
        $('#landlord').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

When the variable is posted into the form from another form the `DIV` doesn't hide.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need javascript for this, just hide the element with CSS based on the PHP variable ?

```
<input type="text" id="showhidediv" name="showhidediv" value="<?php echo $ta;?>">

<div id="landlord" style="display:<?php echo $ta==2 ? 'block':'none' ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I used this and it works a treat, thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
var show= $('#showhidediv').val();
```

instead of

```
var show=('#showhidediv');
```

Comment: Thanks I tried what you have written and still it doesn't hide once the value in the input is what's needed to hide the `DIV`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is the value posting in from another form?  It sounds like we are missing some other code here.

JsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/S5TZv/

Change the value in the HTML in the form from 1 to 2 and run and then back and it works.  To do more than this we need how you are submitting the POST and if it is changing anything, when it is submitted and if you need to call the function again if the page is not reloading... if you are using an AJAX call or not to resubmit the POST.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var show= $('#showhidediv').val();
    if(show == 2) {
        $('#landlord').show();
    }
    else if(show == 1)
    {
        $('#landlord').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks yes, I see what you mean it works as the code should through jsfiddle, not sure why the `POST` would affect it when posting the variable into the `DIV` itself works

Comment: You didn't tell us how that POST got there.  Just guessing because the full details are not known.  The PHP and CSS answer, while it works is a server side solution.  Javascript or jQuery a client side solution.